# vis.js Get value of a specific time

Tags: vis.js

I'm working with vis.js Graph2d (http://visjs.org).
Is there a way to retrieve the value of a specific datetime?
In the core.js I've found a method that converts a datetime into a position on the screen but I can't find a way to retrieve the value.

In this example, I know the datetime of the red line and I need to retrieve the value of the graph at this datetime (25). 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the y value of a specific datetime.

Comment: If you want to know that for example when clicking in the Graph2d, you could use the method `getEventProperties(event)`.

Comment: getEventProperties only returns the position on the graph. I need the value of a specific point.